# Can I use 'hidden' glyphs from a webfont in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, unicode, webfonts, glyph

I'm using 'Raleway' from Google webfonts in my Wordpress site. The standard number glyphs in this font are 'Old Style', meaning some number go over and others under the baseline. When I download and check out the font in Fontlab, I can see there are glyphs with modern styled numbers, they don't have unicode numbers assigned to them, but they have names like *three.lnum* or *eight.lnum*

Is there a way to display these glyphs from custom fonts in Wordpress? They don't show up in the Special Characters List. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

By adding `font-feature-settings: "lnum" 1;` to the CSS you can force lining numerals.

There is apparently a problem with Raleway hosted at GoogleFonts which hampers the font-feature-settings. This means you have to host the font yourself. Luckily Raleway is free to redistribute.

You can download it from GoogleFonts and run it through the FontSquirrel Webfont Generator. Set options to **Expert**, under **OpenType Flattening** check **Lining Numerals** to set lining numerals as the default for your version of the font.

There is a [great article at codesmite.com](https://www.codesmite.com/article/fixing-raleway-and-similar-fonts-numerals) explaining old style and lining numerals.